# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right) \,dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form

> **how to integrate** $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right) \,dx\,dy$$

## My attempt

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right) \,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy}\right) \,dx\,dy$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2} \ln\left[\frac{1 + \frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy}}{1 - \frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy}}\right] \,dx\,dy$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \ln\left[\frac{xy + x^2 + y^2}{xy - (x^2 + y^2)}\right] \,dx\,dy$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \ln\left[\frac{x^2 + yx + y^2}{-(x^2 - yx + y^2)}\right] \,dx\,dy$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \{\ln(x^2 + yx + y^2) \,dx\,dy - \ln(-1)\left[(x^2 - yx + y^2)\right]\}$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x^2 + yx + y^2) - \ln(-1) - \ln(x^2 - yx + y^2) \,dx \,dy$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \left[\ln(x^2 + yx + y^2) - \ln(x^2 - yx + y^2) - \ln(e^{i\pi})\right] \,dx\,dy$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \left[\int_{0}^{1} [\ln(x^2 + yx + y^2) - \ln(x^2 - yx + y^2)] \,dx - i\pi \int_{0}^{1} 1 \,dx\right] \,dy$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \left[\int_{0}^{1} \ln(x^2 + yx + y^2) \,dx - \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x^2 - yx + y^2) \,dx - i\pi \big[x\big]_{0}^{1}\right] \,dy$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \left[ \ln(1 + y + y^2) - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2x^2 + yx}{x^2 + yx + y^2} \,dx  - \ln(1 - y + y^2) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2x^2 - yx}{x^2 - yx + y^2} \,dx - ix \right]\,dy$$

Comment: Is this not on Romanian Math Magazine?

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. yes

Comment: The question lacks context. It is not at all clear that complex numbers should be used. The OP introduces them ad hoc, in order to make the denominator positive.  You can not do that without justifying your actions. This is bad mathematics, bad science.

Comment: @M.Wind I don’t understand why you downvoted the question. I believe it’s well-posed, and you might be the only one who thinks it lacks context.Are you upset and blaming me because your answer might have received a downvote?

Comment: You do not state the purpose of this exercise. Is it for physics or engineering or pure math? You use variables $x$ and $y$ and  this suggests that the solution is real. But once you recognize that the denominator is negative, you take the minus sign out and add $-\pi i/2$. But that is an arbitrary choice. Other choices are possible. Where is your explanation?

Comment: For example, in the fourth line of your calculation you could have put the minus sign in front of the numerator. This is equally sound. This would lead to a term $+\pi i /2$. Why is this inferior? You say nothing about this important fact. Do you realize that working with the logarithm of negative numbers is tricky ?

Comment: The double integral seems to evaluate to [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+arctanh%28x%2B1%2Fx%29+from+0+to+1). Are you aware there should be a complex solution and which branch of the complex logarithm you are expected to be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

Per symmetry

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right) 
dxdy= 2\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{y} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right) \,dxdy $$
Then, substitute $x=yt$ to reduce the integral to
$$\int_0^1 \tanh^{-1}\left(t+\frac1t\right)dt$$

Comment: Sure, you can do this. But how to proceed? The integrand still does not exist.

Comment: As always, fantastic!!

Answer (score 5):

There is no indication that complex numbers should be used in this exercise. Hence it is tacitly implied that this is a calculation on the real numbers. Now the function $\tanh$ yields a value in the range $(-1,1)$. Hence the inverse function only accepts values in this interval; other values are outside of its domain. In this case we can quickly establish that the argument lies outside, since $x/y + y/x \ge 2$ for all positive values of $x$ and $y$. Therefore the integrand does not exist and the integral is undefined.